# Http Post on Android with Header and File

Tags: android, curl, http-post

I have to replicate thia curl comand in Android :

curl -X POST -F gps_track=@ANTON_MORODER.igc https://myserver -H "api-name:name" -H "api-key:key" -H "user-key:user"  -H "Content-Type: application/json"

I tyed several way but always get 400 from server :

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(doarama_api_url+"/activity");
    httppost.setHeader("api-name",api_name);
    httppost.setHeader("api-key",api_key);
    httppost.setHeader("user-key", AppSettings.getdoaramatUserKey() );
    httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(inIGC), -1);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    Log.d("DOARAMA", "statusCode: " + String.valueOf(statusCode));
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you added internet permision in your manifest?

Comment: And what does that mean, 400? And where do you get that?

Comment: `I have to replicate thia curl comand`. You forgot to explain what this curl command is doing. Where is that 'file' in that command?

Comment: Sorry .. the file was in :

  File gpx_or_igcFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TTLiveTrack24");
  String inIGC = gpx_or_igcFolder.getPath()+ "/" + filename + ".igc";

Comment: 400 ????? What does it mean!!!! And i asked where the file was IN THAT CURL COMMAND. And to explain your curl command. Are you serious or not?

Comment: greenapps : if you are not an expert please do not loose your time. 400 obvoisly is the server replay ( in my statusCode variable )  and means ( Errore HTTP 400 Bad request )

Answer (score 0):

replace:
Accept -> Content-type

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would make this even more understandable to current and future readers.